# download the artifact from jfrog artifactory by using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I created one maven repository and uploaded the artifacts into this repository.
I am trying to download the artifact from jfrog artifact repositoy by using ansible playbook. i have written playbook like this.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: check the latest version file
     get_url:
       url: https://artifactory.com:8081/artifactory/Examplemavenrepo/ext- 
       release-local/anil.tar.gz
       dest: /home/anil/
       checksum: sha256:b2d62aab354a581b3d578c56506321924b2ebc36823f1c527dc6091bd51459e6
```

I getting this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": false,
  "dest": "/home/anil",
  "msg": "Request failed", "response": "HTTP Error 404: Not Found",
  "state": "absent",
  "status_code": 404,
  "url": "https://artifactory.com:8081/artifactory/Examplemavenrepo/ext-release-local/anil.tar.gz"
}
```

After this , i also tried by using api key , i got same error above

Comment: Error 404 means "Not found", have you tried to download this artifact from a browser with this url : `https://artifactory.com:8081/artifactory/Examplemavenrepo/ext-release-local/anil.tar.gz`

Comment: yup. it is downloaded.give some examples regarding this issues

Comment: please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your username and API key to download the artifact.

```
---
- name: Download artifact test
  become: true
  get_url:
    url: your_artifact_url_here
    dest: your_dest_folder_here
    url_username: your_username
    url_password: your_api_key
```

To get your api_key
Go to artifactory url
click on your account in the top-right corner and go to edit your profile.
Enter your local password one more time to access the page and change your password.
On that page, you will see your REST API Key, and Encrypted Password that you can use.